Send a single command through tmux at the start of every pane every session
I am using a Solaris server which I cannot alter even as a normal user for "security reasons", but I still have to daily interact in it.
TLDR I have absolutely no root access to the server, no way to add files in the $HOME and I just want to set up a few tweaks. While using TMUX, all my custom preferences are flushed for the default profile which I can't work with.
I need a method to launch a command (either launch a script or a stty erase ^? ) at every tmux instanctiation.
For context, it was forbidden to use any profile / session alteration as several users go through the same user and the $HOME, .profile and the shell cannot be switched. This also means I cannot change any config file in their default directory.
What I did was :

Launch a first command with my ssh -t connection, which allowed me fix the stty erase ^?
Set a few env vars in a script, which cannot be launched at connection from login, unless I add it in the SSH args as a command on login.
Set a few aliases in a folder. The aliases are pretty much : vim -u ./myfolder/.vimrc or the same with tmux tmux -f ./myfolder/.tmux.

Now I have set up every but the terminal stty erase ^? keeps erasing on every pane, session I set in TMUX. I've read a lot about sending a command on the creation of a session or on multiple windows but nothing about having a small command on the start of any tmux pane, window, session.
Is there any way to do that ? The closest I got was reading the tmux configuration from Arch : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmux
I noticed you could start a non login session or set up custom keys, but both methods failed.

Can you store files for your own use anywhere on the server?  tmux -L SinD_Stuff -f /path/to/your/config/tmux.conf new-session; tmux -L SinD_Stuff attach

Hello, I did do that. The configuration is now set up in a custom folder. The problem arises when I want to split a pane or have a new session, it doesn't load up these changes.
I need a method to have every pane, every session run a few commands at creation.

Can't you just set-option -g default-shell /.../myfolder/mysh and in file mysh have a shell script that ends [ -t 0 ] && stty erase ^? and exec /bin/bash "$@".
